# Right way to return proxy model instance from a base model instance in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, proxy-classes

Say I have models:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Dog(Animal):
    def make_sound(self):
        print "Woof!"
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class Cat(Animal):
    def make_sound(self):
        print "Meow!"
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Let's say I want to do:

```
 animals = Animal.objects.all()
 for animal in animals:
     animal.make_sound()
```

I want to get back a series of Woofs and Meows. Clearly, I could just define a make_sound in the original model that forks based on animal_type, but then every time I add a new animal type (imagine they're in different apps), I'd have to go in and edit that make_sound function. I'd rather just define proxy models and have them define the behavior themselves. From what I can tell, there's no way of returning mixed Cat or Dog instances, but I figured maybe I could define a "get_proxy_model" method on the main class that returns a cat or a dog model.

Surely you could do this, and pass something like the primary key and then just do Cat.objects.get(pk = passed_in_primary_key). But that'd mean doing an extra query for data you already have which seems redundant. Is there any way to turn an animal into a cat or a dog instance in an efficient way? What's the right way to do what I want to achieve?

Comment: You could apply make_sound to the Animal model and add a sound = models.charField() to it as well.

Comment: My example is very simple -- what I'm trying to do requires a bunch of work that depends on the type and can't be stored with the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps make Django models polymorphic using the approach described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/msg/b567b75fe61d5044). That code is in early stages of development, I believe, but worth investigating.

Answer (score 12):

The Metaclass approach proposed by thedk is indeed a very powerful way to go, however, I had to combine it with an answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006753/how-to-convert-request-user-into-a-proxy-auth-user-class) to have the query return a *proxy* model instance. The simplified version of the code adapted to the previous example would be:

```
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

class InheritanceMetaclass(ModelBase):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(InheritanceMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj.get_object()

class Animal(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = InheritanceMetaclass
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    object_class = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.object_class:
            self.object_class = self._meta.module_name
        super(Animal, self).save( *args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self):
        if self.object_class in SUBCLASSES_OF_ANIMAL:
            self.__class__ = SUBCLASSES_OF_ANIMAL[self.object_class]
        return self

class Dog(Animal):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    def make_sound(self):
        print "Woof!"


class Cat(Animal):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    def make_sound(self):
        print "Meow!"


SUBCLASSES_OF_ANIMAL = dict([(cls.__name__, cls) for cls in ANIMAL.__subclasses__()])
```

The advantage of this proxy approach is that no db migration is required upon creation of new subclasses. The drawback is that no specific fields can be added to the subclasses.

I would be happy to have feedback on this approach.

Comment: Great work, wonder if this stands up against real life testing.

Comment: I think it'd be convenient to move the SUBCLASSES_OF_ANIMAL registration to metaclass `__init__`

Comment: years later..why did you implement the logic into `__call__`?

Answer (score 5):

the only way known to the human kind is to use  Metaclass programming.

Here is short answer:

```
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

class InheritanceMetaclass(ModelBase):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(InheritanceMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj.get_object()

class Animal(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = InheritanceMetaclass
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    object_class = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.object_class:
            self.object_class = self._meta.module_name
        super(Animal, self).save( *args, **kwargs)
    def get_object(self):
        if not self.object_class or self._meta.module_name == self.object_class:
            return self
        else:
            return getattr(self, self.object_class)

class Dog(Animal):
    def make_sound(self):
        print "Woof!"


class Cat(Animal):
    def make_sound(self):
        print "Meow!"
```

and the desired result:

```
shell$ ./manage.py shell_plus
From 'models' autoload: Animal, Dog, Cat
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> dog1=Dog(type="Ozzie").save()
>>> cat1=Cat(type="Kitty").save()
>>> dog2=Dog(type="Dozzie").save()
>>> cat2=Cat(type="Kinnie").save()
>>> Animal.objects.all()
[<Dog: Dog object>, <Cat: Cat object>, <Dog: Dog object>, <Cat: Cat object>]
>>> for a in Animal.objects.all():
...    print a.type, a.make_sound()
... 
Ozzie Woof!
None
Kitty Meow!
None
Dozzie Woof!
None
Kinnie Meow!
None
>>>
```

How does it work?

1. Store information about class
   name of the animal - we use
   object_class for that
2. Remove "proxy" meta attribute - we need to
   reverse relation in Django (the bad
   side of this we create extra DB
   table for every child model and
   waste additional DB hit for that,
   the good side we can add some child
   model dependent fields)
3. Customize save() for Animal to save the class
   name in object_class of the object
   that invoke save.
4. Method get_object is needed for referencing
   through reverse relation in Django
   to the Model with name cached in
   object_class.
5. Do this .get_object() "casting" automatically
   every time Animal is instantiate by
   redefining Metaclass of Animal
   model. Metaclass is something like a
   template for a class (just like a
   class is a template for an object).

More information about Metaclass in Python: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta.html

Answer (score 3):

I played around with a lot of ways to do this. In the end the most simple seems to be the way forward.
Override `__init__` of the base class.

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__class__ = eval(self.type)
```

I know eval can be dangerous, bla bla bla, but you can always add safeguarding/validation on the type choice to ensure it's what you want to see.
Besdies that, I can't think of any obvious pitfalls but if i find any i'll mention them/ delete the answer! (yeah i know the question is super old, but hopefully this'll help others with the same problem)

Comment: FYI: found that I needed to add a guard here: `if type(self) == Animal: ...`.  Django seemed to be recursively calling init somehow (looked like something to do with refresh_from_db or deferred fields).

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be side-stepping the question somewhat because it doesn't use proxy models.  However, as the question asks, it does let one write the following (and without having to update the `Animal` class if new types are added)--

```
animals = Animal.objects.all()
for animal in animals:
    animal.make_sound()
```

To avoid metaclass programming, one could use [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  For example--

```
class Animal(models.Model):

    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @property
    def type_instance(self):
        """Return a Dog or Cat object, etc."""
        return globals()[self.type]()

    def make_sound(self):
        return self.type_instance.make_sound()

class Dog(object):
    def make_sound(self):
        print "Woof!"

class Cat(object):
    def make_sound(self):
        print "Meow!"
```

If the `Dog` and `Cat` classes need access to the `Animal` instance, you could also adjust the `type_instance()` method above to pass what it needs to the class constructor (e.g. `self`).