# Assigning a proxy model instance to foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have a django auth user proxy model that has some extra permissions attached to it like so:

```
class User(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        permissions = (
            ("write_messages","May add new messages to front page"),
            ("view_maps","Can view the maps section"),
        )
```

Elsewhere in the model I have an object that has User as a foreign key:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    creation_date   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner           = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In one of my views I attempt to create a new project using the current user as the owner

```
@login_required
def new_project(request):
    project = Project.objects.create(owner=request.user)
```

This, however, returns the error:

```
Cannot assign "<User: mwetter>": "Project.owner" must be a "User" instance.
```

I'm assuming that the foreign key owner in the project object is referring to the base class for Django User instead of my proxy class. Is there a way to refer to my proxy user as a foreign key instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006753/how-to-convert-request-user-into-a-proxy-auth-user-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling your proxy class `User`, which is guaranteed to lead to confusion between that and `django.contrib.auth.models.User`? Why not `UserProxy`, or `MyUser`? Then it could be distinguished whenever you use it.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a good point actually. Up until now I haven't used `User` in any context other than the built-in functions like `user.has_perm()`. I can't remember my original reasoning behind using the same name, so I'll try changing it to see what breaks.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the best answer since its the obvious step that I should have taken. At this point I'm delving into the jungle of extended user models and all of the joy that it entails.

Answer (score 22):

In addition to what @DavidRobinson said, you need to be careful about creating foreign keys to proxy models. A proxy model is still a subclass of the model it proxies, despite being for all intents and purposes the same as the model. If you have a foreign key to the proxy it will not accept the base class, however a foreign key to the base class *will* accept the the proxy. Take the following for example.

Given:

```
class UserProxy(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    ...

class User(models.Model):
    ...
```

The following will raise an exception:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProxy)

user = User.objects.get(username='some_user')
instance = SomeModel.objects.create(user=user)
```

But, the following will work fine:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

user = UserProxy.objects.get(username='some_user')
instance = SomeModel.objects.create(user=user)
```

This is due to the directionality of the relationship. `UserProxy` *is-a* `User`, but `User` is *not* a `UserProxy`.

Comment: Although I accepted DavidRobinson's answer, thank you for the extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign id instead of object

```
project = Project.objects.create(owner_id=request.user.pk)
```