# Creating instances of Django proxy models from their base class

Tags: python, django

I have a series of models that look like this:

```
class Analysis(models.Model):
    analysis_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def important_method(self):
        ...do stuff...


class SpecialAnalysis(Analysis):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def important_method(self):
        ...something different...
```

This is all pretty standard. However, what I'd like to do is automatically convert an `Analysis` model to a proxy model based on the value of the `analysis_type` field. For example, I'd like to be able to write code that looks like this:

```
>>> analysis = Analysis.objects.create(analysis_type="nothing_special")
>>> analysis.__class__
<class 'my_app.models.Analysis'>

>>> analysis = Analysis.objects.create(analysis_type="special")
>>> analysis.__class__
<class 'my_app.models.SpecialAnalysis'>

>>> analysis = Analysis.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> analysis.__class__
<class 'my_app.models.SpecialAnalysis'>

>>> # calls the ``important_method`` of the correct model
>>> for analysis in Analysis.objects.all():
...     analysis.important_method()
```

Is this even remotely possible? A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218867/right-way-to-return-proxy-model-instance-from-a-base-model-instance-in-django), which actually gives some code for the iteration example, but it still leaves me with the question of how to get or create an instance of a proxy class from its parent. I suppose I could just override a bunch of manager methods, but I feel like there must be a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I haven't found a "clean" or "elegant" way to do this. When I ran into this problem I solved it by cheating Python a little bit.

```
class Check(models.Model):
    check_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, editable=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, choices=TYPES)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=METHODS)
    'More fields.'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Check, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.check_type:
            map = {'TypeA': Check_A,
                'TypeB': Check_B,
                'TypeC': Check_C}
            self.__class__ = map.get(self.check_type, Check)

    def run(self):
        'Do the normal stuff'
        pass


class Check_A(Check):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def run(self):
        'Do something different'
        pass

class Check_B(Check):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def run(self):
        'Do something different'
        pass


class Check_C(Check):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def run(self):
        'Do something different'
        pass
```

It's not really clean but it was the easiest hack to find which solved my problem.

Maybe this is helps you, maybe it doesn't.

I'm also hoping someone else has a more pythonic solution to this problem since I'm counting the days till this method fails and comes back to haunt me..

Comment: Well, this is definitely cleaner than the crazy stuff I was trying. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your method is unlikely to fail in and of itself but manual mapping definitely doesn't scale well; future visitors would be better served using the Model.__subclasses__() method to get the list of proxy models and querying some/all of them dynamically as needed.

Answer (score 7):

This is a great approach and I don't particularly see it as a cheat. Here is IMHO some enhancements to the `__init__` function so it doesn't has to change when you add more classes.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Analysis, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.__type and type(self) == Analysis:
        raise Exception("We should never create a base Analysis object. Please create a child proxy class instead.")

    for _class in Analysis.__subclasses__():
        if self.check_type == _class.__name__:
            self.__class__ = _class
            break

def save(self, **kwargs):
    self.check_type = self.__class__.__name__
    super(Analysis, self).save(**kwargs)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ooh nice. Didn't know about `__subclasses__`, it would definitely improve maintainability.