# Django proxy model: parent class accessing sub-class methods

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to wrap my head around how proxy model works.  Supposed I have a base class called Animal, and I would like to implement two sub-classes: Dog and Cow.  They have the same data requirements, so I don't really want to create two separate tables.  So I am trying using proxy models:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    animal_type = models.CharField(choices=(('Dog','Dog'),('Cow','Cow')))

    def get_sound(self):
        if animal_type == 'Dog':
            return self.dog.get_sound()    #doesn't work
        elif self.animal_type == 'Cow':
            return self.cow.get_sound()    #doesn't work

class Dog(Animal):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

    def get_sound(self):
        return 'Woof'

class Cow(Animal):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

    def get_sound(self):
        return 'Moo'
```

The problem I have is, how can I access the sub-class methods from the parent class?  I have it as `self.dog.get_sound()`.  This is possible in multi-table inheritance, but does not work in a proxy model.

```
>>obj = Animal.objects.create(name='Max', animal_type='Dog')
>>obj.get_sound()
'Woof'    <-- what I'd like it to return
```

Is proxy model the wrong way to do this?  Would prefer to keep one table.

Comment: I think you don't understand object inheritance. Try to make new object `obj = Dog.objects.create(name='Max', animal_type='Dog')` and you will get Woof

Comment: Yes, I can do that.  But supposed I have an object id, but I don't know what type of animal the object is and all I care is to run `get_sound()`.  Currently, I would have to get `Animal.objects.get(id=id).animal_type`, then once I figure out it's a dog (using if/then), do `Dog.objects.get(id=id).get_sound()`.  Is it possible to do this from within the Animal class?

Comment: I guess I can do this in Animal get_sound().  `if animal_type == 'Dog': return Dog.objects.get(id=self.id).get_sound()`.  That seems inefficient to have to initiate the object twice (once as an Animal and once as a Dog).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525301/django-inheritance-and-polymorphism-with-proxy-models

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's not going to work. Behind the scenes Django creates a OneToOne foreign key for each inherited model, you're right about it, except in the case of proxy models ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#base-class-restrictions)). Proxy models are not meant to be used this way, they work exactly like the original model, sometimes in a subset of the original table (like your example), extra methods, etc. If you use a proxy model you shouldn't need to use the original table, as you want.

I have a few suggestions for you:

```
class DogManager(Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(kind='Dog')  # Literal is not good

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'kind': 'Dog'})
        return super().create(**kwargs)


class CowManager(Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(kind='Cow')  # Literal is not good

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'kind': 'Cow'})
        return super().create(**kwargs)


class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    # I've changed the name because I don't like variables with 'type' in the name
    kind = models.CharField(choices=(('Dog','Dog'),('Cow','Cow')))


class Dog(Animal):

    objects = DogManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy=True

    def get_sound(self):
        return 'Woof'


class Cow(Animal):

    objects = CowManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy=True

    def get_sound(self):
        return 'Moo'
```

And now you don't need to call `Animal` class, as you have a subset of your original data in those two proxy models [proxy managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-model-managers).

```
instance = Dog.objects.create(name='Max')
instance.get_sound()  # Woof

Dog.objects.all() # all animals with kind 'Dog'
Cow.objects.all() # all animals with kind 'Cow'
```

Comment: Essentially, I'd like to be able to call all animals and get their sound `for animal in Animals.objects.all(): animal.get_sound()` and I think the approach above doesn't do that as I would need to do it for each kind of animal.

Comment: I do have a solution, which is once I get an Animal instance, I look at the type of animal and creates an instance of that animal.  However, instead of using `Dog.objects.get(id=self.id)` which would hit the database a second time, I would do `Dog(**attrs)` where `attrs={f.name: getattr(self, f.name) for f in self._meta.fields}`.  `self` here refers to the Animal instance.  I think this works but what I'd like to know is whether I should be using a model other than the proxy model to accomplish my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    class Type(models.TextChoices):
        Dog = ('dog', 'Dog')
        Cow = ('cow', 'Cow')

    name = models.CharField()
    animal_type = models.CharField(choices=Type.choices)

    def get_subclass_instance(self):
        subclasses = {
            self.Type.choices.Dog: Dog,
            self.Type.choices.Cow: Cow,
        }
        instance = subclasses[self.type].objects.get(id=self.id)
        return instance

    def get_sound(self):
        self.get_subclass_instance().get_sound()


class Dog(Animal):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

    def get_sound(self):
        return 'Woof'

class Cow(Animal):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

    def get_sound(self):
        return 'Moo'
```